# how to do multi-language regex for a SPA routing in laravel?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, vuejs2, single-page-application

im using vue and `laravel` to do `SPA` application.
in my app im using `vue-router` in `history mode`, and its works like magic.

to make my `SPA` work properly even when you refresh a page im using:

```
Route::get('/{vue?}', function() {
    return view('main');
})->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

and it works, but, only in english.
when im trying to use `Hebrew` in my `URL`, its not working.
i thing the problem is the `regex` im using

please help me, thanks !

Comment: Try to add `\x{0590}-\x{05FF}` after `[`: `'[\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\/\w.-]*'`. Or `\p{Hebrew}`: `[\p{Hebrew}\/\w.-]*`. Or perhaps, that will work, too - `'(*UTF)(*UCP)[\/\w\.-]*'`

Comment: can you please explane the diffrance ?

Comment: Did any of them work as expected?

Comment: yeah, i checked it now. only this one worked: `'[\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\/\w.-]*'`, can you explain the code please ? and thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 '[\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\/\w.-]*'
```

It matches zero or more chars defined inside `[...]`, a character class:

- `\x{0590}-\x{05FF}` - a range of Unicode code points that constitute a Hebrew character range
- `\/` - a literal forward slash
- `\w`- word chars, i.e. ASCII letters, digits and an underscore
- `.` - a dot
- `-` - a hyphen.

Comment: i checked it deeply, and i saw that some chars isnt working, for example:
`)(_`

Comment: @anonicode: The [`[\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\/\w.-]` matches `_` but does not match `(` and `)`](https://regex101.com/r/osLM8l/1). Also, note that `*` makes it match an empty string. Could you please precise the current issue?

Comment: yeah, the regex you gave me is great, but i also need it to work for special chars : `(`  `)` `=` `+` `}` `{`  `\`   `|`   `@` `!` `?`  `,` `:` `;` `[` `]`

Comment: @anonicode There is no problem here, just add them - [`[\x{0590}-\x{05FF}\/\w()=+{}\`|@!?,:;\[\].-]*`](https://regex101.com/r/DtZrWr/1)